# Does kiwi tcms have an upload limit?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I use the import tool provided by eliyahasan/kiwi-tcms-import-util, but I found the tool that only 3 test cases can be uploaded at most,  and then return 400 bad request.

This is my sample code and csv file: https://github.com/StayFantasy/kiwi_practice

Can anyone give me some suggestions?? Thanks.

This is error message from pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/etern/Documents/Practice/Python/kiwitcms/csvImport.py", line 105, in <module>
    m.createTestCases()
  File "C:/Users/etern/Documents/Practice/Python/kiwitcms/csvImport.py", line 101, in createTestCases
    self.rpc_client.exec.TestPlan.add_case(3, case_id)
  File "C:\Users\etern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1109, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Users\etern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1450, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "C:\Users\etern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1153, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\etern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1183, in single_request
    raise ProtocolError(
xmlrpc.client.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for localhost/xml-rpc/: 400 Bad Request>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: well... when I reinstalled it was no problem...

Answer (score 1):

> I use the import tool provided by eliyahasan/kiwi-tcms-import-util, but I found the tool that only 3 test cases can be uploaded at most, and then return 400 bad request.

To make an official answer - this is a 3rd party tool and we have no idea how it works or what it is supposed to be doing. Ask the original author for help.

Comment: Thank you , I re-install kiwi and solved the problem